# setTimeout vs setInterval in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi can we change setInterval to setTimeout function, it is working fine I want to know can it is done with setTimeout

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var current = $('#counter').text();
    var endvalue = 50
    $('a').click(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            if (current === endvalue) {

            } else {
                current++;
                $('#counter').text(current)
            }
        }, 50)
    })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="counter">0</div>
<a href="#">Click</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to recursively call setTimeout and see how that is done? Or you just want to call setTimeout to run it once?

Comment: ´setTimeout´is executed only once, ´setInetrval´is a executed after interval until clearInterval is called

Comment: You could do that quite easily with `setTimeout()`, but why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function to contain the setTimeout, and call it within the function

```
$(function() {
    var current = $('#counter').text();
    var endvalue = 50;

    function timeoutVersion() {
        if (current === endvalue) {return false;} else {
            current++;
            $('#counter').text(current);
        }
        setTimeout(timeoutVersion, 50);
    }

    $('a').click(function() {
        timeoutVersion();
    })
})​
```

[Live Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3nzhd/show/) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/3nzhd/)

However it's much better to clear the `setInterval` with `clearInterval` after you're done with it:

```
$(function() {
    var current = $('#counter').text();
    var endvalue = 50
    $('a').click(function() {
        var storedInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if (current === endvalue) {
                clearInterval(storedInterval);
            } else {
                current++;
                $('#counter').text(current)
            }
        }, 50)
    })
})​
```

[Live Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3nzhd/1/show/) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/3nzhd/1/)

---

To answer your question - yes, you can change `setInterval` with `setTimeout` with some minor changes to the code you've used for `setInterval`

Comment: well buddy thats a good technique but instead of writing more code, you should use setInterval function....

Comment: I want to know one thing why setTimeout execute in every 50 millisecond inside the function  it should execute once.

Comment: A timeout means a single break/pause in time, while an interval [in JavaScript] means a constant recurring re-run of a block of code with breaks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `setInterval()` to execute a function say, every 1000 milliseconds, which is equal to 1 second, the function will be triggered every 1000 milliseconds no matter how long the function takes to execute, whereas if you tried to do the same with `setTimeout()`, if the function was taking, say 500 milliseconds to execute, your total time gap between execution of functions will be 1500 milliseconds.

Comment: This is incorrect. If the function takes longer than 1000 milliseconds your time will then be off, and `setInterval` will try to catch up using up a higher % of the processor `setTimeout` can be used in such a way to monitor the actual time and get back on track if done properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval says this answer is correct

Comment: Look at the higher voted answer :P http://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince it may not of been accepted by the original asker, but the community valued it more.

Comment: Yeah i agree with this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval#731625 , but you cannot say that my answer is `incorrect`

Comment: The portion that's incorrect is `the function will be triggered every 1000 milliseconds no matter how long the function takes to execute`, it will *attempt* to execute it every 1000 ms, but the triggered function can take longer which will throw the interval off so it is an incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call the same function recursively using setTimeout to get the effect of setInterval. Note that in setTimeout, you have to manually check to stop the loop if you use it recursively. But setInterval function returns a id, with which you can call the clearInterval function to stop it whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend `setTimeout` over `setInterval` [for reasons better explained by bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/a/731625/322395) While my answer is close to extramaster's I dont advocate the use of interval just to have the ability to clear it. An easier approach is just don't call the next timeout once you've reached your goal

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/Aa7YU/)**

```
 $(function() {
    var current = $('#counter').text();
    var endvalue = 50;

    function increment() {
        if (current !== endvalue) {
            current++;
            $('#counter').text(current)
            setTimeout(increment, 50);
        }

    }

    $('a').click(function() {
        increment();
    })
})​;
```